# Chromatic polynomial, how to solve?

Tags: polynomials

I have an assignment coming up, and one of the chapters are regarding graphs and more specific Chromatic polynomials, now I know that Chromatic Polynomial is the least amount of colors you can choose on the corners without the  neighbors having the same color, but assignments like when they show a graph and they say 'calculate the Chromatic polynomial', and the answer is something like t(t - 1)*(t - 2)^3.
I really have no idea what they do or how to do it, I would really appreciate if someone could start with posting simple examples and then step by step explain what I'm supposed to do and why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the deletion-contraction formula for chromatic polynomials?

Comment: I've heard of it, but not quite sure I understand it.

Comment: Feel free to try to explain it to me.

I'm not sure what the purpose of edge contraction is really.

Comment: Well the point of the contraction-deletion formula in this context is that it lets you write the chromatic polynomial of your graph in terms of the chromatic polynomials of two smaller graphs.  You can repeat this until you have expressed it in terms of small, easy to understand pieces.

Comment: The "chromatic function" (my term)  $f_G(n)$ of a graph $G$ is the number of ways to legally colour $G$ with $n$ colours. The _chromatic number_ of $G$ is the least $n$ for which $f_G(n)\ne 0$. It turns out that $f_G(n)$ is a polynomial, so we call it the _chromatic polynomial_ of $G$. For things other than graphs, there's absolutely no reason for $f_X(n)$ to be a polynomial. The contraction-deletion formula is one way to see why it has to be a polynomial for graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of a tree computed using deletion-contraction, there are other ways to do this but this illustrates the method:

Claim: For any tree on $n$ vertices, the chromatic polynomial is $t(t-1)^{n-1}$.

Proof: We will proceed by induction using the deletion-contraction formula. For $n=1$ there is only one tree, namely a point which clearly has chromatic polynomial $t$.

Let $T$ be a tree on $n+1$ vertices, and let $e$ be an edge connected to a leaf $v$.  Deletion-contraction tells us that the chromatic polynomial of $T$ is equal to the chromatic polynomial of $T-e$ (T with e deleted) minus the chromatic polynomial of $T/e$ (T with e contracted to a point).

$T-e$ is a tree on $n$ vertices disjoint union a point, so by induction we know its chromatic polynomial is $t(t-1)^{n-1} \times t$ (chromatic polynomials disconnected graphs are the products of the chromatic polynomials of the pieces).

$T/e$ is a tree on $n$ vertices so by induction we have that its chromatic polynomial is $t(t-1)^{n-1}$.

So the chromatic polynomial of $T$ is:

$t(t-1)^{n-1} \times t - t(t-1)^{n-1} = t(t-1)^n$

completing the induction.